# rectangles inside a matrix - dotted and continuous lines

Tags: matrices, arydshln

I'm trying to implement the appendix image, making an script in LaTeX.

After consulting some forums I obtained the next script but the dotted lines don't appear.

PS. I'm new in Latex!

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{equation} \label{eq10}   T_6^{0} = \left [  
\begin{tabular}{cccc:cc}   \cdashline{1-4}   \multicolumn{2}{:l}{1}   
& 0     & 0    & \multicolumn{2}{c:} {\(p_x__{req}\)}   \\  
\multicolumn{2}{:l}{0}    & -1    & 0    & \multicolumn{2}{c:}
{\(p_y__{req}\)}    \\   \multicolumn{2}{:l}{0}    & 0     & -1   &
\multicolumn{2}{c:} {\(p_z__{req}\)}  \\ \cdashline{1-4}  
\multicolumn{2}{c}{0}     & 0     & 0    & \multicolumn{2}{c:} {1}   
\end{tabular}  \right ] \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]